# C++ "pointer being freed was not allocated" Error

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following code:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
MovieLibrary* library = new MovieLibrary(maxMovies);
delete[] library; // This throws the error.
```

**MovieLibrary.cpp**

```cpp
MovieLibrary::MovieLibrary(int maxMovies) {
    this->maxMovies = maxMovies;
    this->numMovies = 0;
    this->movies = new Movie*[maxMovies];
}

MovieLibrary::~MovieLibrary() {
    for (int i=0; i<this->numMovies; i++) {
        delete this->movies[i];
    }
    delete[] this->movies;
}
```

**Movie.cpp**

```cpp
Movie::Movie(Text* title, Text* publisher, int year) {
    this->title = title;
    this->publisher = publisher;
    this->year = year;
}
```

This is not all the code, but it's all the code I believe should be required to find the cause of the error. I'm pretty novice to C++ and dynamic memory allocation. Running the program gives me a "pointer being freed was not allocated" and I've researched but to no avail. Most posts just say it's trying to clear something not initialized with malloc or new, but I mean `MovieLibrary* library = new MovieLibrary(maxMovies);` is initialized with new, so I'm lost.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `delete[] library;` should be `delete library;`.

Comment: `delete` frees memory allocated with `new`.  `delete[]` frees memory allocated with `new[]`.  It is *undefined behavior* to mismatch them.  Inside your `MovieLibrary`, you are matching them correctly (provided you handle copy/move construction/assignment properly per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)), but in your `main` you are not.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use pointers here. Using standard containers (std::vector) and other standard features (std::string) will remove all the fidely memory management that you are currently doing by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @PeteBecker and @RemyLebeau:

Use `delete library;`, rather than `delete[] library;`

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that you meant to use square brackets with `new`:

```
MovieLibrary* library = new MovieLibrary[maxMovies];
delete[] library; // This should not throw an error.
```

You should almost never use `delete` and `new` directly. There are complicated set of cases when you would still want to use `new` and `delete` directly, but this is not one of them.

Instead, prefer to use standard containers such as `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<MovieLibrary> library(maxMovies);
// no delete[] library, since std::vector does it for you
```

If you are not allowed to use `std::vector` then the next best thing in this case are `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique()`. With these, the chance of making the same mistake as in your question are much smaller. This solution for dynamic arrays has been available since C++14 (for regular pointers since C++11):

```
std::unique_ptr<MovieLibrary[]> library = std::make_unique<MovieLibrary[]>(maxMovies);
// no need to delete library, it will be done for you at scope exit.
```

Besides, the code has other messed up things. It seems that you wanted to create a dynamic array of pointers to objects, but you attempted to create a dynamic array of objects instead. Please clarify what you intend to do. It is likely that you really need only a vector of MovieLibrary objects, nothing more, but there is not enough information in the question to tell.